# Sysadmin password storing

Tags: patterns-and-practices, server, operating-systems, passwords

I'm quite unexperienced in the sysadmin area. Now I'm facing the responsability of managing two (remote) servers. I'm working in an informal organization.

So I have passwords for the OS's users, database users and so on.

I want to be able to store the access information securely in case someone else has to take my place.

Now my doubts are about how and where to store this information. My first thought was to use a gpg encrypted file and save it in the cloud, example google drive, but for some reason it seems to me that this is not a good approach.

Are there good/standard practices on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Company LastPass account. Move on. (Other password management services are available)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about the software engineering topics of this site. Superuser.SE or Serverfault.SE are probably better suited.

Comment: @DocBrown Oh, ok, I thougt it was on topic. Maybe migrate it?

Comment: @DocBrown although the answer is good enough for me, I'm applying it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [KeePass](https://keepass.info/) to store sensitive information, and have some password databases that are shared with colleagues. It is free and open source, approved by security people at my work, and can be run without installation (which means that we can have not only the password database but also the actual application on our server – no need for new colleagues to install new software just to get access to passwords).

I/we use a master password, which of course is sensitive information. KeePass can also be used with a key file (which then should be stored separately).

One of the advantages of this approach is that password databases can be passed on to someone else, both as in "share with yet another person" and "I leave this to you".

Having a backup of the password database will be important, since you will lose all your passwords if the database is lost. For my personal stuff I have a backup using Dropbox. At work we have an internal backup running. (Dropbox is not my favourite, since it gives access to US authorities, but I consider my passwords to be safe since they are encrypted in a strong way.)

EDIT: There are plugins to KeePass that allows auto-pasting passwords in web browsers. I don't use these, since the idea of having another application automatically read my passwords seems ... bad. I find some other applications (such as Strongbox on iPhone) highly useful.

Answer (score 0):

Dare I suggest a low-tech answer?

Write the details on a piece of paper.  Seal it into an envelope and hand it to a trusted person in your organisation.

Comment: ... and that "trusted person" should take your piece of paper and /burn/ it, unread.  
Just because you trust the person you give it to does not mean that it will always remain in their possession or control, meaning that someone less trust-worthy might get hold of it.

Answer (score 0):

In my current job we use KeePass, just as described by Itangalo.

In a previous team we used [blackbox](https://github.com/StackExchange/blackbox), a tool to use PGP to encrypt secret files in git repositories. This is very similar to your first thought. The biggest problem could be finding co-workers with working PGP setups.

In my experience both options are good for small groups of users. It gets more complicated with multiple groups or hierarchies or automation; for example with central admins and multiple product teams and a Jenkins server, all having access to different credentials. I know one team in this situation, they decided to move everything into AWS Secrets Manager in order to use the access control policies there.